# Google Pay Passes API for trains and buses

Tags: google-api, google-pay

I need to import a train and bus ticket into the Google Pay app. Currently, there are only options for a flight boarding pass.
There are also API's called 'Google Pay APIs for India', which got this feature, but I doubt about using it (because I'm not from India).
What should I use to add a ticket for bus or train to my customers Google Pay app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Google Pay Transit Passes :

https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/transit-passes/overview